# How to detect lowercase letters in Python?

Tags: python, string, lowercase, letter

I need to know if there is a function that detects the lowercase letters in a string. Say I started writing this program:

```
s = input('Type a word')
```

Would there be a function that lets me detect a lowercase letter within the string s? Possibly ending up with assigning those letters to a different variable, or just printing the lowercase letters or number of lowercase letters.

While those would be what I would like to do with it I'm most interested in how to detect the presence of lowercase letters. The simplest methods would be welcome.

Comment: `if any(c for c in s if c.islower())` detects the presence of at least one lowercase letter.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x?

Comment: Why upvote a wrong answer @NoctisSkytower? It should be `any(filter(str.islower, s))`

Comment: @stanleyli Thanks for pointing that out! Must have mistyped it the first time.

Answer (score 52):

To check if a character is lower case, use the `islower` method of `str`. This simple imperative program prints all the lowercase letters in your string:

```
for c in s:
    if c.islower():
         print c
```

Note that in Python 3 you should use `print(c)` instead of `print c`.

---

> Possibly ending up with assigning those letters to a different variable.

To do this I would suggest using a list comprehension, though you may not have covered this yet in your course:

```
>>> s = 'abCd'
>>> lowercase_letters = [c for c in s if c.islower()]
>>> print lowercase_letters
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Or to get a string you can use `''.join` with a generator:

```
>>> lowercase_letters = ''.join(c for c in s if c.islower())
>>> print lowercase_letters
'abd'
```

Answer (score 13):

There are 2 different ways you can look for lowercase characters:

1. Use [`str.islower()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) to find lowercase characters. Combined with a list comprehension, you can gather all lowercase letters:

   ```
   lowercase = [c for c in s if c.islower()]
   ```
2. You could use a regular expression:

   ```
   import re

   lc = re.compile('[a-z]+')
   lowercase = lc.findall(s)
   ```

The first method returns a list of individual characters, the second returns a list of character *groups*:

```
>>> import re
>>> lc = re.compile('[a-z]+')
>>> lc.findall('AbcDeif')
['bc', 'eif']
```

Comment: The first snippet does not what you think it does.

Comment: Looks better )) BTW, this seems to be a valid use case for `filter` - something no one mentioned so far.

Comment: @thg435: I don't think `filter(lambda c: c.islower(), s)` or `filter(methodcaller('islower'), s)` is that readable, really.

Comment: @thg435 I think answers should be Pythonic. Yours is... well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: how about `filter(str.islower, s)`?

Comment: @thg435: Sure, it's a little cleaner; it won't work for `unicode` but it'll work great for the OP.

Answer (score 7):

There are many methods to this, here are some of them:

1. Using the predefined `str` method `islower()`:

   ```
   >>> c = 'a'
   >>> c.islower()
   True
   ```
2. Using the `ord()` function to check whether the ASCII code of the letter is in the range of the ASCII codes of the lowercase characters:

   ```
   >>> c = 'a'
   >>> ord(c) in range(97, 123)
   True
   ```
3. Checking if the letter is equal to it's lowercase form:

   ```
   >>> c = 'a'
   >>> c.lower() == c
   True
   ```
4. Checking if the letter is in the list `ascii_lowercase` of the `string` module:

   ```
   >>> from string import ascii_lowercase
   >>> c = 'a'
   >>> c in ascii_lowercase
   True
   ```

But that may not be all, you can find your own ways if you don't like these ones: D.

Finally, let's start detecting:

```
d = str(input('enter a string : '))
lowers = [c for c in d if c.islower()]

# here i used islower() because it's the shortest and most-reliable
# one (being a predefined function), using this list comprehension
# is (probably) the most efficient way of doing this
```

Comment: What does this add to the other, existing answers?

Comment: The second and third method aren't mentioned above

Answer (score 3):

You should use `raw_input` to take a string input. then use `islower` method of `str` object.

```
s = raw_input('Type a word')
l = []
for c in s.strip():
    if c.islower():
        print c
        l.append(c)
print 'Total number of lowercase letters: %d'%(len(l) + 1)
```

Just do -

```
dir(s)
```

and you will find `islower` and other attributes of `str`

Comment: Note: `raw_input()` in Python 2.x is replaced by `input()` in Python 3.x. This is important since the author hasn't specified which version he is using.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = raw_input('Type a word: ')
slower=''.join(re.findall(r'[a-z]',s))
supper=''.join(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',s))
print slower, supper
```

Prints:

```
Type a word: A Title of a Book
itleofaook ATB
```

Or you can use a list comprehension / generator expression:

```
slower=''.join(c for c in s if c.islower())
supper=''.join(c for c in s if c.isupper())
print slower, supper
```

Prints:

```
Type a word: A Title of a Book
itleofaook ATB
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the libraries and want simple answer then the code is given below:

```
  def swap_alpha(test_string):
      new_string = ""
      for i in test_string:
          if i.upper() in test_string:
              new_string += i.lower()

          elif i.lower():
                new_string += i.upper()

          else:
              return "invalid "

      return new_string


user_string = input("enter the string:")
updated = swap_alpha(user_string)
print(updated)
```